# Flow: How do I access children.type.displayName

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have a component that will apply some extra logic if the children is the component type that I expect using display name.

```
const ToggleButton = ({
  children,
}) => {
  // ...

  const isIcon = children?.type?.displayName === 'Icon';

  // ...
}
```

The code runs perfectly when being passed a string, component, list of components. But when I add flow it starts to complain saying:

```
Cannot get `children?.type` because property `type` is missing in `$Iterable`
```

I'm using `React.Node` but should I be defining children as a different type?

```
// @flow

const ToggleButton = ({
  children: React.Node,
}) => {
  // ...

  const isIcon = children?.type?.displayName === 'Icon';

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React has a function called `React.isValidElement` but the problem is that in flow this does not do a type validation.

Instead I created a type safe predicate function to handle this for me

```
export default (obj: React.Node, name?: string): boolean %checks => (
  !!obj
  && typeof obj !== 'boolean'
  && typeof obj !== 'string'
  && typeof obj !== 'number'
  && typeof obj === 'object'
  && !!obj.type
  && (name ? !!obj.type?.displayName && obj.type.displayName === name : !!obj.type)
);
```

And it can be used in this way to validate if the `displayName` is what I expect

```
const isIcon = isReactElement(children, 'Icon');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const isIcon = children?.type?.displayName === 'Icon';
```

means that the children can be null/undefined. However, in the flow definition, you haven't specified that.

So do this:

```js
const ToggleButton = ({
  children?: React.Node,
}) => {
  // ...

  const isIcon = children?.type?.displayName === 'Icon';

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes I've done this also but still get the error. I believe it's because `React.Node`'s key, `React.Element` satisfies but the other cases don't so they throw an error. But I assume because I'm using optional chaining it should check that `type` doesn't exist before proceeding so it should be safe.